# determine the subset Q

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

let $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the Banach space of
bounded continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$, we denote $\Vert.\Vert$ the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$. 
so im trying to determine Q a subset of $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$, if it exists, such that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$
$$\Vert x-y\Vert^2=\sup_{u\in Q}\big(u(x)-u(y)\big)$$
i did prove it for $\Vert.\Vert$ but i didnt for $\Vert.\Vert^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such set exists.  The defining condition implies that any $u\in Q$ is [Holder continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) with exponent $2$, and only constant maps satisfy this.